# Error in Swift Package: Could not find module 'XXXX' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator,

Tags: swift, swift-package, rosetta

There is issue with Swift package manager i added and it is showing error

```
Could not find module 'XXX' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator,
```

1. It is working with Rosetta in Simulator and in actual device with Xcode 14.3.1. But i am looking for options with out Rosetta.
2. Tried to solve issue with Build settings

[image: Build Settings for Pods and project target looks like this]

3. Had also tried adding below code snipet in PodFile:

> post_install do |installer_representation|
> installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
> target.build_configurations.each do |config|
> config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
> config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
> end
> end end

But nothing works. Is there any solution to update some settings in Swift package or in main project settings or i can add some scripts such that i do not have to use Rosetta.